# Htaccess Redirect to different folders

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have 2 folders in my root directory (**admin** and **dist**) i need to redirect 
www.domain.name/admin --> to **/admin** or to **/admin/wp-admin**(nor sure if its going to work ok)
everything else to **/dist** folder: www.domain.name, www.domain.name/blog etc.

Comment: Sorry for not providing my htaccess. Have no idea what im writing atm

Comment: I suggest you give the `edit` link below your question a try and revise your question so that it makes sense. Thanks.